# Webpack is changing a hash in a sourcemap for a file that wasn't changed

Tags: webpack, source-maps

In my common.js entry point, I am importing a big .scss file which loads the Bootstrap core (from node_modules)..

```
import Layzr from 'layzr.js';
import './js/vendor/bootstrap/transition';
import './js/vendor/bootstrap/collapse';
import './js/vendor/scrollTo';
import './sass/common.scss'; // this guy
```

this guy looks a bit like that

```
// common.scss
@import "variables.scss";
@import "bootstrap-custom";
//.. other imports
```

and how does webpack know where to find bootstrap in the end?

```
{
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              includePaths: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets'),//that's how
              ]
}
```

My problem is that everytime I run webpack it changes a hash related to boostrap import and the common.js.map file changes

```
{"version":3,"sources":[
"webpack:///common/common.js",
"webpack:///webpack/bootstrap 12b09b93ea869cb3a747",
"webpack:///......
```

why is this hash changing since I didn't change anything
(and what is this hash to begin with..)

Answer (score 3):

By default, the unique hash for a given webpack compilation appears alongside the reference to webpack's manifest/runtime in your final entry bundle's sourcemap. In the sourcemap, that reference is called `webpack:///webpack/bootstrap`, which is unrelated to Twitter's Bootstrap and thus extremely confusing.

I'm guessing your webpack implementation uses a plugin (https://github.com/soundcloud/chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin, for example) that moves the manifest reference out of the bundled js, so the entry bundle itself will not change every single time anything elsewhere in your source changes. These plugins don't seem to interfere with sourcemap creation, however, so you end up with a modified sourcemap but an unmodified bundle.

This can be clarified a bit by breaking your manifest out into its own bundle, as illustrated here: https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/separating-manifest/

Answer (score 0):

When you’re using `[hash]`, webpack computes one hash per bundle and if one file changes, the whole hash changes (or at least that is the way I understand it). Try using `chunkhash`, which is computed for each chunk

https://webpack.github.io/docs/long-term-caching.html